# Finding expected value of operating units

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

Given $N$ operating units, every unit consists $k$ elements.

If one element is missing from one operating unit, it stops working.
The units operate independently.

When $m$ elements are removed from the system, what will be the expected value of the number of operating units?

So, we have to choose $m$ element out of $k$ groups.

If we choose so that $\,m=k\,$, the result can be minimum $\,0\,$ or maximum $\,N-1\,$ operating unit.

In case $\,m<k\,$, it is minimum $\,1\,$ or maximum $\,N-1\,$ operating units possible.

If $\,m>k\,$ it can be minimum $\,0\,$ or maximum $\,N-2\,$ operating units.

How should I continue the solution?

Comment: What is the probability that a given element is working?  Do elements fail independently?  You are asking a probability question, but you haven't given any probabilistic assumptions.  Also, I'm not sure that you mean what you say in the first sentence.  Did you mean to say that there are $N$ units, each comprising $k$ elements, so that there are $Nk$ elements in all.  The way it is written, it appears that there are $Nk^2$ elements.  Finally, to do this problem, use linearity of expectation.

Comment: Yes, it really wasn't understandable. I edited it.

Comment: @dret375 Please clarify if I understood it correctly. There are N operating units. Each operating unit consists of k elements. So there are a total of N*k elements in total and each element is equally likely to be picked. If at least one of the k elements in an operating unit is picked out, that operating unit stops working. Please say if my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: @Two_eyed_Potat Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @dret375 Instead of providing entire solution, I will say how you can continue. As already mentioned you can use the linearity of the expectation. Try to find the probability that a particular operating unit is working after removing m elements from overall N*k elements. (Hint: Finding the probability that a particular operating unit is not working is easy). Once you get that probability you can use linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 1):

As I read the question, it seems that there are a total of $Nk$ elements in clusters of $k$ elements in a unit, and a total of $m$ elements fail.

P(an element in unit $i$ fails) = $\frac{m}{Nk}$

P(an element in unit $i$ does *not* fail) = $1- \frac{m}{Nk}$

Let $X$ be an indicator random variable that is = $1$ if none of the $k$ elements in that unit fail, and $0$ otherwise

$P(X_i) = (1- \frac{m}{Nk})^k = Y, say $

The expected value of an indicator variable is the same as the *Pr* indicated by it, so $\mathbb{E}(X_i) = Y$

and by the linearity of expectations over $N$ units, $\mathbb{E}(X) = NY$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't stated well.  I'm assuming that each element has a probability $p$ that it is operating.  If the elements fail independently, then the probability that a given $k$-unit is working is $p^k$, and by linearity of expectation, the expected number of working units is $Np^k$.

To see that the last statement is true, use indicator functions.  For $i=1,2,\dots,N$, let $X_i$ be a random variable that is $1$ if unit number $i$ is working and $0$ if is not, so that the number of working units is $\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$.  By linearity of expectation,, $$E(\sum_{i=1}^NX_i=\sum_{i=1}^NE(X_i)=Np^k$$